# Where to get the MySql UDF that has sql_exec?

Tags: php, mysql

I have found a couple pages that have broken links to this UDF, but I can't find any valid links.

I have read a couple of posts that say it is on Github, but when I search Github I don't see it.

What I am trying to do is run a PHP script from a MySQL script.  I have seen on many sites that the simple way to do this is to use sql_exec.

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear what you are looking for here

Comment: The UDF package that contain the sql_exec function - does anyone have a link to where this is?

sql_exec isn't part of the core install in mysql, it has to be installed via a UDF package.  I have only found broken links to this package.

(For windows)

Answer (score 1):

The Github MySQL UDF repository is [here](https://github.com/mysqludf).

The one that will let you make OS calls is named [lib_mysqludf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys).

I would suggest you consider a way to accomplish what you want that does not require use of a UDF.  You could for example have a polling routine that queries a queue table and runs your external program using the data from the queue, or even a queue by itself, as it's not clear from your question what the connection between data in mysql and this external php script is.

Comment: Thanks!  I have today off, but I will go through this as soon as I get back to work.  When/if it's what I want I will definitely mark this as answered.